# Running a get link serverside, with php

Tags: php

When my PHP script runs, I would like to run a link like this server side:

```
http://77.33.xx.xx/s/addtoqueue.php?action=store&filename=myprettypicture&link=http://i69.servimg.com/u/f69/13/29/70/44/facebo10.png
```

Im doing this for storing the images on a own separate images server. The link is adding the image to a queue.

How can I execute this link correct?

I did this so far:

```
$link = 'http://77.33.xx.xx/s/addtoqueue.php?action=store&filename='.$filename.'&link=$link;
```

But dont know how to run this?

And would it by the way be smart to urlencode() and urldecode() the $link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't build the query string myself like that, but use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) in preference:

```
$url = 'http://77.33.xx.xx/s/addtoqueue.php';
$params = array(
    'action' => 'store',
    'filename' => $filename,
    'link' => $link,
);
$link = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

To actually make a call to the URL you can use a number of techniques, but my favourite in this case would be [curl](http://php.net/curl). Here is an adapted version of the [example from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Other options include [`file_get_contents($link);`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) if the [fopen wrappers have been enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

### Additional response for comments

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

`$response` now contains the response from the URL. From the [`curl_exec()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

For more information on the curl options you can use checkout the [`curl_setopt()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish to check what the response of the url is, if the link executed outputs "OK" or "FAIL", how can i do this?

Comment: Please see the additional code I have put together for you although you could use the appropriate HTTP headers to indicate success (200) and failure (500) instead of relying on the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to call your link.
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php